# How can I make React as CPU efficient as vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, optimization

I have a simple script that updates a number every 1000th of a second. If I write it out in vanilla (standard) JS and run it, it consumes around 40% of my CPU (on all 4 cores). If I implement an analogous feature in React, it consumes around 60% of my CPU with constant spikes to 100% on at least one of the cores.

Here is the code.

In vanilla JS (https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-dew-12vli)

index.html

```html
<body>
    <h1>Vanilla JS</h1>
    <div>
      <div>Counter: <span class="counter">1</span></div>
      <div>Counter: <span class="counter">2</span></div>
      <div>Counter: <span class="counter">3</span></div>
      <div>Counter: <span class="counter">4</span></div>
      <div>Counter: <span class="counter">5</span></div>
      <div>Counter: <span class="counter">6</span></div>
      <div>Counter: <span class="counter">7</span></div>
      <div>Counter: <span class="counter">8</span></div>
      <div>Counter: <span class="counter">9</span></div>
      <div>Counter: <span class="counter">10</span></div>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
```

script.js

```js
const list = document.getElementsByClassName("counter");

for (let item of list) {
  setInterval(() => {
    item.innerHTML = Number(item.innerHTML) + 0.001;
  }, 1);
}
```

And in React (https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-wood-puhdu)

App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import Counter from "./Counter";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React</h1>
      <Counter start="1" />
      <Counter start="2" />
      <Counter start="3" />
      <Counter start="4" />
      <Counter start="5" />
      <Counter start="6" />
      <Counter start="7" />
      <Counter start="8" />
      <Counter start="9" />
      <Counter start="10" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Counter.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Counter(props) {
  const [amt, setAmt] = useState(parseInt(props.start, 10));

  useEffect(() => {
    // setAmt(parseInt(props.start));
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setAmt(amt => amt + 0.001);
    }, 1);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        counter:{" "}
        <span id={props.start} className="counter">
          {amt}
        </span>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Stepping this down to 1/100th of a second keeps things a little under control, but still React is more CPU intensive than vanilla JS...

Two questions:

1. How can I make this react component as performant as its analogous JavaScript script?
2. How can I make this script more efficient in general?

Comment: @user120242 react keys are really only useful when rendering lists of elements, see [Lists & Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html). To the OP, react is already really optimized. As much as it can be for an entire framework of DOM diffing and state management. Refer to [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) and [Optimizing performance](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html).  Is there a deeper underlying performance issue you are trying to solve for or just simply exploring react performance?

Comment: I noticed it on a project I'm working on where the CPU spike is concerning. I'm hoping to figure out how to fix it so I'm being  a considerate developer for my end users and their power consumption.

Comment: It's great to be a considerate developer, but this feels borderline premature-optimization. My guess is the spikes are just react doing its thing, i.e. state updated so it's diffing the virtualDOM and committing (flushing) updates to the actual DOM. I would expect this if you're updating state on the order of hundreds/thousands of times per second. You're defining ***a lot*** of anonymous callback functions so they are likely building up and getting garbage collected in bulk by the browser.

Comment: Well, to be more specific in the project I'm getting 60% cpu usage, causing the fans to spin up on my machine... I distilled the issue down to this example to see whether it was the screen update or the underlying calcs... It's a little of both, I'm sure, but the above difference is not insignificant.

Comment: Actually, scratch that, I see you're instantiating the interval once on mount, probably not a bunch of anonymous callbacks.

Comment: Note: you can always write vanilla JS to outperform React.  By definition.  Just like you can always write asm to outperform anything else.  It's just very unlikely that you can (other than for contrived examples and for specific domains, and even then difference is most likely negligible), and the code quality and productiveness would most likely suffer for it (as the complexity of the code rises).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't expect setInterval to actually call once every millisecond. It usually won't. On my machine, I get 253, but yours may be different.

```
//Logs the number of calls done in one second
let counter = 0
let interval = setInterval(function() {counter++}, 1)
setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(interval);console.log(counter);counter=0}, 1000)
```

Second of all, abstraction, like that done by ReactJS, is only going to make code slower - assuming that you wrote yours perfectly. You're never going to get a speed boost by making an additional function call. What you gain from libraries is easy of use, well optimized code, and code that is widely compatible, all without great effort from you.

Don't obsess over performance. This code is editing 10k elements per second, and only using 40% of your CPU. Very few webpages edit 10k elements per second, and those that do are likely to be using progressive rendering to prevent you from ever noticing a performance issue.

Lastly, if your goal is to do a timer, use Date.now() so that a bit of lag on the host machine doesn't cause problems. Additionally, only run your code as much as is useful, or in your case, once every frame, try using window.requestAnimationFrame() or setInterval(function, 16)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified Timeouts/Intervals are throttled to >= 4ms

Comment: interesting tip: `window.request.AnimationFrame()`. In the real world, it's updating at a much more realistic interval, but I took it to an extreme to amplify the issue...

Comment: Your extreme sample has the same problem as most micro-benchmarks.  It's no longer testing that which would be relevant to the real bottleneck.  You should probably clarify what use case you are doing these tests for.

Comment: @Trees4theForest, in this case, amplifying the issue only created an issue where there wasn't one before. As fast as computers are, modifying the DOM 10k times per second can be expected to have performance implications - and when you are dealing with 10k operations per second, even a tiny bit of overhead can add up quickly.